# Вопрос по CSS (style) и правилам HTML

Tags: html, css

```html
<div id="Kontainer">
  <style>1-gorizont {background-color: gray;}</style>
  <div class="1-gorizont">1 Горизонтальный блок</div>
  
  <style>.2-gorizont {border: 1px solid gray;}</style>
  <div class="2-gorizont">2 Горизонтальный блок</div>
  
  <style>.3-gorizont {background-color: red;}</style>
  <div class="3-gorizont">3 Горизонтальный блок</div>
  
  <style>.4-gorizont {background: green;}</style>
  <div class="4-gorizont">4 Горизонтальный блок</div>
</div>
```

1. Грубо говоря , страницы сделаны из 1 контейнера div , а в нем 4-5
   горизонтальных блоков.
2. Можно ли перед каждым этим блоком грузить предназначенные ему стили
   и скрипты , а не совать все огромным файлом в шапку или подвал ?

Просто когда так делаю , validator.w3.org ругается , якобы нельзя помещать стили внутри div.

Вот что говорит валидатор:

- EN оригинал -
  [image: https://image.prntscr.com/image/oabqzUEJQ2OeWqApYSXCAQ.png]
- RUS перевод -
  [image: https://image.prntscr.com/image/1akCqGL7SsqF9Ku9x4507Q.png]

Comment: Картинки вы можете загрузить прямо в вопрос.

Comment: а код будет как ты делаешь?

Comment: Нельзя помещать стили внутри div. Стили должны быть только внутри head. 2 — нет, нельзя.

Comment: Почему нельзя ? 
Для оптимизации вообще советует сам гугл убирать в подвал или встраивать в сам код HTML.

Comment: @andreymal я думал по иписанию будет понятно , добавил грубый пример для понимания , но тут он не хочет работать(

Comment: Гугл вас пытается научить плохому, стили должны быть только в head и нигде больше.

Comment: @andreymal Почему именно так как вы говорите должно быть ? Ведь мы делаем сайты помимо людей , еще и для Google с Яндекс.

Comment: Потому что так прописано в стандарте HTML5. Стандарту даже гугл не указ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй написать так

```
<div id="Kontainer">
    <div style="background-color: gray;">1 Горизонтальный блок</div>

    <div style="border: 1px solid gray;">2 Горизонтальный блок</div>

    <div style="background-color: red;">3 Горизонтальный блок</div>

    <div style="background: green;">4 Горизонтальный блок</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Несмотря на то, что стандарт это разрешает, гугл это запрещает)

Comment: да нет же , так мне не нужно ;)
Я привел грубый пример , я же не могу засунуть все 3000 свои строк сюда...
Я спрашивал про пример отдельный от блоков , а не встраивать в них...
И сам Pagespeed советует именно так делать как вы показали , но тогда я не смогу делать и @media для моб , планшетов и т.д.

Comment: рекомендуют выбрать ответ , а ответов нету)